# Splitting large code into Modules to Call

Tags: vba, split, module, ms-word, call

My end goal was to generate text into a TextBox (let's call it TextBox06) based on the values inserted into a series of Textboxes -- let's name them TextBox01, TextBox02, TextBox03, TextBox04, TextBox05. These TextBoxes are in a Userform (let's call it Userform01).
These TextBoxes can have a lot of different values and combinations (over 50 values each, and depending on which order the values are placed in the textboxes there will be a different output). Moral of the story: code probably works, but gives "procedure too large" error with no real way around it (pretty sure I have shrunk the code as much as possible, but there just aren't any more generic statements that repeat, and most of it must be a bruteforce-style method of inserting most of the combinations individually).

So I went looking on the internet for a way to split the code. I tried using the "call procedure" feature. What I did was:

I created two new Modules (Module01 and Module02) in the same "project".

I split the big code half in Module01, and half in Module02. The Modules' content is something like this:

```
Sub Module01()
    
[half the code]
    
End Sub
```

I wrote the following lines of code in each sub of the textboxes involved (this is in Userform01).

```
Private Sub TextBox01_Change()
    Application.Run ("Module01")
    Application.Run ("Module02")
End Sub
```

[Then five more copies for Private Sub TextBox02_Change () until Private Sub TextBox06_Change () included]

Assuming this is even the correct way of doing it, I then hit a roadblock. Apparently, copy-pasting the big code in Module01 and Module02 wasn't enough. From what I understood, the program doesn't seem to understand what the TextBox01.Text (and the like) values in the code are. So I tried looking for a solution to THAT, and found several possible codes, none of which seems to have worked so far. The one that I currently have is this:

```
Sub Module01()

Dim Text01 As String
Set Text01 = TextBox01.Text
[repeat for Text02 to Text06 included]

[half the code]

End Sub
```

[repeat for Module02 with the other half of the code]

Assuming that I'm even on the right track when it comes to properly using the "call" function, what is the proper way to make this work (i.e. how do I correctly reference the TextBox01.Text content in the Module, so I can then call the Modules in the Userform01) ?

Comment: Very difficult to make suggestions without some idea of what your Subs *actually look like* - currently this is sort of a bit abstract.  What exact errors(s) are you getting, and with what code?  Eg. you cannot use `Set` to assign a String.

Comment: How many procedures (i.e., "Sub" or "Function" statements) were in your original project? Am I understanding correctly that you tried splitting into separate procedures but now you're further splitting procedures into separate modules?

Comment: To Tim Williams: right now, as soon as I try to type anything into one of the textboxes (for example TextBox01), the error message says "Compile error: Object required". It takes me to the Module01 page, and highlights (in blue, like when you select some text with your mouse) the following: "Text01 =" (from the second line, where in my post I wrote "Set Text01 = TextBox01.Text"). If I give the "ok" to the error message, it then highlights (in yellow) the "Sub Module01 ()" part (which from what I've seen means "the erorr is in this sub).

Comment: To bugdrown: if you mean in my Userform in general, not all that many before this massive chunk of new code I tried to add yesterday. Specifically regarding the new code, I tried taking the whole new code I wanted to add, and added it to a Module. I know you are making a distinction between "procedure" and "module", but the solutions to this problem have mixed them up constantly and I don't know which one is which myself.

Comment: As for how many statements there are, it's approximately 300 "IF" statements (7 "And"-parts "IF" condition, and a single result if the condition is met), and they were all part of the same "Sub" I guess (the sub being "Private Sub TextBox01_Change()"), although they probably needed to be duplicated for each TextBox involved. I have no idea what a "procedure" really is. I'm trying to avoid confusion using the nomenclature I can actually read in the VBA interface ("project", "userform", "module") to avoid even more confusion.

Comment: Oh, and back to Tim Williams again: the whole code is about 300 variants of this: https://i.ibb.co/cCds80b/image.png Just for the record, the actual text input in TextBox01 and output in TextBox06 are something else entirely (not that it should be relevant, anyway).